# Adding custom image field in data tab of Opencart

Tags: php, mysql

I want to add a custom image field to upload a image in data tab of opencart. The image is displayed but after click on save button the image disappears and the image not saved in mysql database also. So please help me.
  I changed the existing code as follows to upload an image:

**In controller/catalog/product.php**

```
if (isset($this->request->post['backgroundimage'])) {
        $this->data['backgroundimage'] = $this->request->post['backgroundimage'];
    } elseif (!empty($product_info)) {
        $this->data['backgroundimage'] = $product_info['backgroundimage'];
    } else {
        $this->data['backgroundimage'] = '';
    }


    $this->load->model('tool/image');

    if (isset($this->request->post['backgroundimage']) && file_exists(DIR_IMAGE . $this->request->post['backgroundimage'])) {
        $this->data['thumb'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize($this->request->post['backgroundimage'], 100, 100);
    } elseif (!empty($product_info) && $product_info['backgroundimage'] && file_exists(DIR_IMAGE . $product_info['backgroundimage'])) {
        $this->data['thumb'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize($product_info['backgroundimage'], 100, 100);
    } else {
        $this->data['thumb'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize('no_image.jpg', 100, 100);
    }
```

**In view/template/catalog/product_form.tpl**

```
<tr>
              <td><?php echo $entry_backgroundimage; ?></td>
              <td><div class="image"><img src="<?php echo $thumb2; ?>" alt="" id="thumb2" /><br />
                  <input type="hidden" name="image2" value="<?php echo $backgroundimage; ?>" id="image2" />
                  <a onclick="image_upload('image2', 'thumb2');"><?php echo $text_browse; ?></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a onclick="$('#thumb2').attr('src', '<?php echo $no_image; ?>'); $('#image2').attr('value', '');"><?php echo $text_clear; ?></a></div></td>
            </tr>
```

**In model/catalog/product.php**

```
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product SET backgroundimage = '" . $this->db->escape($data['image2']) . "',product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of
    `$this->db->escape($data['image2'])`
use this
    `$this->db->escape(html_entity_decode($data['image2'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'))`